# Shopping Cart Price Rule Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, coupon, promotions

Want to know how we can **Set Shopping Cart Price Rule** in Magento 1.9.2 for specific Category?

i have 1 product which is under multiple categories but i only want to put Condition on One Particular Category which means if i choose the item from that particular Category then the Rule will apply and if i choose the same product while i am in an other category then the rule will not apply.

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use catalog product price rules.
Shopping cart price rules will apply at cart.
Catalog product price rules applied on category as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i will check on that and will let you know if it got work.

Comment: i try apply the Catalog Product Price rule but it state away cutting the Price from the Product. Even though same product is coming from another category. As per my requirement, 1 product is in many different categories but when i move on the Website this rule will apply only the Category i wanted to.

Comment: this will not work. Catalog Price Rules are not made to match your requirment

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution for this case. A custom Module is needed to implement this.

Your will have to find a suitable event. something like

```
prepare_catalog_product_collection_prices
```

implement your logic inside an observer and store your rule data as category attributes.

Comment: How we can achieve custom Module??? i asking because i am new to Magento.

Comment: the most prominent module skeleton is Ultimate Module Creator by marius. https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9
there are also Kickstarter
https://www.mgt-commerce.com/kickstarter/ and 
Inchoo_Alpha
http://inchoo.net/magento/simple-magento-module-generator/

if your question has been answered please accept and upvote ;)